# Scraping past page 25 with KimonoAPI from Kimonolabs

Tags: web-scraping, kimono

I'm trying to capture some information from an architects register but I can only scrape down 25 pages, how can I access pages after page 25?

Example URL http://architects-register.org.uk/search/address/london

Answer (score 0):

try to add the following parameters to the source-url of your api

```
kimoffset=xxx&kimlimit=1000
```

where xxx are "elements page number x number of pages you mean to skip"